# Command executed correctly from powershell, but not in npm script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build, create-react-app

I'm trying to append the content of a js file to the end of my server-worker.js in create-react-app.
I don't want to eject, so this is the easiest way of setting up caching for all fetch responses (i think!)

I have created a js file called sw-epilog.js, which contains the js code i want to attach.

in my package.json i've added:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && yarn sw-epilog",
"sw-epilog": "type src/sw-epilog.js >> build/service-worker.js",
```

when i run `type src/sw-epilog.js >> build/service-worker.js` on my powershell, the content is copied over to service-worker. but there is an invalid character every other character in the output.

when i run `npm run build` the console says:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ type src/sw-epilog.js >> build/service-worker.js
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I'm on windows 10.

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3"
```